# How do you create irregular, but regular, shapes in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, shapes, mask, clipping-mask, bezier-curve

I asked a [question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/163087/in-inkscape-how-to-make-different-parts-of-a-bitmap-have-different-opacity/163090) about opacity in Inkscape and one suggested solution was to draw a mask. Well, I tried that but failed completely, probably because I don't know the "craft" required to draw bezier curves etc.

[image]

I would like to draw a path/create a shape over the rectangular (with two rounded corners) dark blueish shape in the middle of the above image. It needs to be perfect, but with such a regular shape, it shouldn't be super difficult to achieve that, should it? It is not like masking hair/fur!

I have checked the Inkscape documentation, e.g., here https://inkscape.org/doc/tutorials/advanced/tutorial-advanced.html, but it doesn't really cover how you actually do it.

**How do draw a shape like the one I want to draw here?** Step by step, like it is the first time (well, not really) I use a computer.

Comment: There are tutorials on youtube which show how to use the Pen tool to draw Bézier paths in Inkscape.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer (because drawing paths is shown well in tutorials), but maybe interesting;

[image]

In the left I have a group of 3 rectangles which is made by selecting them and applying Object > Group.  As you see in the Layers & Objects panel, there's 3 rectangles grouped,

In the right I have a bitmap image. It's a rasterized rounded rectangle, so there's some transparent areas in the corners, because images are always rectangles.

In the next image in the left the red image is moved below the group:

[image]

The image is not exactly in the middle. You can see its bounding box, because I have selected all.

In the right there's another screenshot after Object > Mask > Set Mask has been applied. The opacity mask made parts of the red image more or less transparent.

In the next image a new blue shape is drawn and moved partially behind the masked red image:

[image]

In the Layers & Objects panel you see that the image icon has "mask reminder". The mask doesn't affect the blue shape because it was not born when the mask was applied to the red image.